# Set delay or timeout before initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delay, delayed-execution

I'm working with a script that needs to delay (or have a setTimeout) before any animation loads or initializes, but can't seem to figure out where to put it.

<strike>As for delay, if I'm not mistaken, this is used mainly with jquery...So for example: `$('id or class here').delay(2000);` ...Correct?</strike>

As for the setTimeout, if I'm not mistaken, it would be with javascript correct?  If so, wouldn't it look something similar to this: `setTimeout(function () {function_name},2000);` or a slightly different variation of that?

Regardless of these two approaches and trying to add it where I think it should go (using either variations mentioned above), for some reason it just doesn't work right. The console isn't really helping either to check for errors.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to set a delay of 2s (2000ms) before anything starts or initializes.

**JS CODE (Where I believe the issue lies):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Additional code here...
    // start
    BG.init();

    // Additional code here...
    }
});
```

Comment: you can also use `setTimeOut` like this:  `setTimeout(function_name,2000);`

Comment: Correct, this is a slightly different variation of `setTimeout` that I have also used....I'm just not sure where to place it.

Comment: can you isolate the code you're asking about in a another little code block? that should help people read it better

Comment: What console errors are you returning

Comment: One mentioned that BG.init isn't a function - most of the time though, there were no errors that were displaying... :/

Comment: Please read this from the stackoverflow guidinelines, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You don't need to post 5 pages of code to illustrate your issue here and ask about how to create a delay.

Comment: @jfriend00 - At first I only had the (In-Full) code listed and not the isolated blocks of code that I added later.  I only added that as per a request from Omarjmh.  Regardless, my question has been answered and thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Michael - My comment was because I'm attempting to help you understand better what to include in your question next time.  A **minimal**, complete and verifiable example is what is expected here.  It is sometimes a bit of work to understand the tradeoff between minimal and complete, but it never means just pasting in lots of irrelevant code.  You could have put `// ... other code goes here` for 98% of what you posted because it was mostly irrelevant to the question.  Please work on writing answers that follow the guidelines as it makes the community better.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Will do, Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Put this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
```

And then where you have this:

```
});

// wrapper for background animation functionality
var BG = {
```

Put this:

```
    }, 2000);
});

// wrapper for background animation functionality
var BG = {
```

And then, if you don't want to incur the wrath of everyone in the world, indent the stuff inside that new function we just created by one more level. 'Cause indentation is the stuff of life.

Comment: Thank you VoteyDisciple!  I actually tried this, however, I didn't quite have it right - the closing `}, 2000);` I place on the `.ready` closing tags - weird thing is that doing that didn't display any errors in the console on my end - I used your approach and it seems to be working now!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of 'useless' code for us to help you. Next time share only on a *need-to-know* bases :)

I've edited your $document.ready block to include the timeout, have a look-see:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function initiationProcess() {
      // setup logo image
      BG.logo = new Image();
      BG.logo.onload = function() {
        BG.logo_loaded = true;
        BG.showLogo();
      }
      // /../ more code /../
      // wire ticker listener
      Ticker.addListener(BG.tick);
      // start
      BG.init();
      // /../ more code /../
   }

   setTimeout(initiationProcess, 2000);
});
```

**Edit**:
I'd also like to note that it's considered bad practise (not to mention that it might result in buggy code) to only partly use semicolons in your script file. There's [points and counterpoints](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-semicolons) to using semicolons, but pick a standard and stick to it!

Comment: Is this a more efficient way?  Or is what `VoteyDisciple` posted the better alternative of the two?